# filter entries by similar class name and removing them

Tags: jquery, html

i would like to display only one entry per user, what i have done is adding the username to the class so what happen is this:

```
 <div class="bla ronen"></div>
 <div class="bla ronen"></div>
 <div class="bla david"></div>
 <div class="bla david"></div>
 <div class="bla jhon"></div>
 <div class="bla jhon"></div>
 <div class="bla jhon"></div>
 <div class="bla jhon"></div>
```

i want the result to be

```
 <div class="bla ronen"></div>
 <div class="bla david"></div>
 <div class="bla john"></div>
```

i think it's best to use jquery here and hide anything which is not the fisrt of the same class but not sure how to do so...

thanks!

Comment: This should probably be a server-side task..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dUdLf/1/)**

Use this snippet,

`.each()` iterates over each `<div>`, the current class in stored in `temp`. If the class of next div matches with temp, remove it.

```
var temp = '';

$('div').each(function () {
    if (temp === $(this).attr('class')) {
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        temp = $(this).attr('class');
    }
});
```

Or to make it more compact,

```
var temp = '';

$('div').each(function () {
    temp === $(this).attr('class') ? $(this).remove() : temp=$(this).attr('class');

});
```

Comment: `.each()` iterates over each `<div>`, the current class in stored in `temp`. If the class of next div matches with temp, remove it. If, the next div has new class, set it to `temp`